# phpMyAdmin Selecting certain string from column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to select just the a href url portion of the following longtext value (in wp_posts table and post_content column)

```
Profonest Unique Hardware - <a href="https://bit.ly/_ADXTxn" target="_blank" rel="noopener">https://bit.ly/_ADXTxn</a>
Pandora Games 3D / Arcade: <a href="https://bit.ly/_AATHpd" target="_blank" rel="noopener">https://bit.ly/_AATHpd</a>
Wedoit Handhelds / Consoles:
```

So all I would need would be the actual URL in the ahref

eg: **https://bit.ly/_ADXTxn** located within this  and not the link before closing the ahref

There are two links and I would like to grab both if possible.

https://bit.ly/_ADXTxn

https://bit.ly/_AATHpd

I've tried to get the exact terminolgy to search for a solution but I'm guessing regex or % in a WHERE post_content LIKE style query?

Comment: Have you done any research in the [MYSQL Manual - String Functions section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html)?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have not, but I have come across Substring and Substring Index which I am assuming would be part of the solution here.

Comment: I'm close to a solution but it's not fully correct as I would want to extract multiple bitly links. Here's what code is close to working (for at least one link)

```SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING('<a href="https://bit.ly/_ADXTxn" target="_blank"' FROM LOCATE('https://bit.ly','<a href="https://bit.ly/_ADXTxn" target="_blank"')),' ',LENGTH('https://bit.ly%"') - LENGTH(replace('https://bit.ly%"', ' ', '')) +1
) as result;```